# Selecting dynamic columns Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a pretty hard time into figuring out how to ask this. I have 2 tables, one is a list of 'Orders' with the registry time, and another table 'Activity' where i have a register of the time these Orders made it to a process.

What i dont get how to do is the next thing, i need to be able to determine with a query the amount of time for each Order since the last Process.

Table: Ordenes

```
| Id | Numero | flujo_id | LastOrder |            FechaRegistro |
|----|--------|----------|-----------|--------------------------|
|  1 |    111 |        1 |         0 | August, 13 2015 13:25:00 |
|  2 |    222 |        1 |         2 | August, 13 2015 13:25:00 |
|  3 |    333 |        1 |         4 | August, 13 2015 13:25:00 |
|  4 |    444 |        1 |         3 | August, 13 2015 13:25:00 |
```

Table: Actividad

```
| Id |             TiempoInicio | TiempoFin | Proceso_Id | Orden_Id |
|----|--------------------------|-----------|------------|----------|
|  7 | August, 13 2015 13:30:00 |    (null) |          1 |        2 |
|  8 | August, 13 2015 13:50:00 |    (null) |          2 |        2 |
|  9 | August, 13 2015 13:30:00 |    (null) |          1 |        3 |
| 10 | August, 13 2015 13:50:00 |    (null) |          2 |        3 |
| 11 | August, 13 2015 14:20:00 |    (null) |          3 |        3 |
| 12 | August, 13 2015 14:25:00 |    (null) |          4 |        3 |
| 13 | August, 13 2015 13:30:00 |    (null) |          1 |        4 |
| 14 | August, 13 2015 13:50:00 |    (null) |          2 |        4 |
| 15 | August, 13 2015 14:20:00 |    (null) |          3 |        4 |
```

Table: Procesos

```
| Id | Estacion_Id |                                             Nombre |                 TiempoStd |
|----|-------------|----------------------------------------------------|---------------------------|
|  1 |           1 |      Informacion <br/>tecnica para <br/>aprobacion | January, 01 1970 00:02:00 |
|  2 |           2 | Aprobacion de<br/> Informacion<br/>Tecnica cliente | January, 01 1970 00:24:00 |
|  3 |           3 |             Informacion<br/>Tecnica de<br/>Proceso | January, 01 1970 00:04:00 |
|  4 |           4 |           Compra y<br/>Recepcion de<br/>Materiales | January, 01 1970 02:00:00 |
```

Expected Output.

```
| Id | Numero |            FechaRegistro |   P1   |   P2   |   P3   |   P4   |
|----|--------|--------------------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  1 |    111 | August, 13 2015 13:25:00 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|  2 |    222 | August, 13 2015 13:25:00 | 5:00   | 20:00  | (null) | (null) |
|  3 |    333 | August, 13 2015 13:25:00 | 5:00   | 20:00  | 30:00  | 5:00   |
|  4 |    444 | August, 13 2015 13:25:00 | 5:00   | 20:00  | 30:00  | (null) |
```

What i dont know how to do is being able to do the call dynamically so that i would get P1,P2,P3, until Pn columns n = the number of rows on 'Procesos' table. And for the time calculation i do have an idea, but since I dont know how to get these columns i can't try it.

Here is a fiddle with the tables loaded up. [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c9e4/3)

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work - or the link doesn't anyway

Comment: @RamRaider i just tried it, and it does, can you re-try?

Comment: OK, it was noscript blocking the link - my apologies..opens fine in chrome!

Comment: How are you getting `5:00` for id 2,3,4 in `P1` column of expected output table?

Comment: @Crazy2crack So, from the table Actividad, the column Orden_id is the value for the Id in Orden, there you can see the time of registration. and count on for the next Processes.

Comment: But the dates are different in both tables right? it is `Aug 13` in Ordenes and `Aug 20` in Actividad.

Comment: @Crazy2crack ohh, crap, you are so right, should of been Aug 13 for simplicity, ill edit. thanks for the observation

Comment: some good eyeballs there @Crazy2crack

Comment: You're confusing data storage and retrieval with data display. Issues of display are best left to the presentation layer / application level code, if that's available.

Comment: @Strawberry would it be easier to do this if storing the actual time from last process rather than the timestamp itself?

Comment: @pato.llaguno I don't know what you mean, but I can't see how it's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with something like below. It might look little fuzzy.

```
select ordenes.Id,Numero,FechaRegistro,m.p1,a.p2,b.p3,c.p4 from Ordenes 
left join (select ordenes.id,
              TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Ordenes.FechaRegistro,min(Actividad.TiempoInicio )) P1 
           from Ordenes
           left join Actividad on ordenes.id=Actividad.orden_id
           group by Actividad.orden_id) as m on ordenes.id=m.id
left join (select Orden_Id,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,min(TiempoInicio ),max(TiempoInicio )) P2 
           from actividad 
           where Proceso_Id in ('1','2')
           group by orden_id) as a  on ordenes.id=a.orden_id
left join 
(select Orden_Id,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,min(TiempoInicio ),max(TiempoInicio )) P3 
        from actividad 
        where Proceso_Id in ('2','3')
        group by orden_id) as b on ordenes.id=b.orden_id
left join 
(select Orden_Id,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,min(TiempoInicio ),max(TiempoInicio )) P4 
        from actividad 
        where Proceso_Id in ('3','4')
        group by orden_id) as c on ordenes.id=c.orden_id
order by id;
```

Output I'm getting

```
| Id | Numero |            FechaRegistro |   P1   |   P2   |   P3   |   P4   |
|----|--------|--------------------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  1 |    111 | August, 13 2015 13:25:00 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|  2 |    222 | August, 13 2015 13:25:00 | 5      | 20     | 0      | (null) |
|  3 |    333 | August, 13 2015 13:25:00 | 5      | 20     | 30     | 5      |
|  4 |    444 | August, 13 2015 13:25:00 | 5      | 20     | 30     | 0      |
```

It **doesn't meet** all the requirements. But it might be useful atleast as reference to proceed further

[**DEMO Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d2431/1)

Comment: Thx for the try, but im still with my main problem which is the dtnamic part, if storing the difference already would it be easier to get this dynamically? So having stored the 5 min, 20, etc?

Comment: man, im trying to understand how your query works out and i don't really understand why would i get some 0 instead of null in id 2 and 4, do you happen to know how to explain it to me?

Comment: Sry i was kind of busy. That `0` is coming because in that case both `Min` and `max` will be same date. So `select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2015-08-13 13:30:00','2015-08-13 13:30:00');` will give `0` .

Comment: Which part you are referring to get as dynamic here?

Comment: so, not necessarily i will be having 4 processes, might have more, or even less, so somehow i want to iterate, my first thought was to use your code but use some for loops to build the query statement with php beforehand, i don't know if that is less effective since ill have to aad an extra call to the db to get the number of processes.

Comment: Do you happen to know if i have to make some changes for it to work in php? i placed some ticks ` for it to stop giving syntax problems, now i get no errors, but get false with this call `$res = mysql_query($sql,$conn); ChromePhp::log($res);` the connection is stablished correctly and `mysql_select_db($db,$conn)` this one too.